# Angular CLI not enforcing ESLint rules

Tags: angular, angular-eslint

I have successfully configured ESLint in my Angular project and my rules are enforced for already existing files. As an example I enforce double quotes.

```
"rules": {
 "quotes": [2, "double", { "avoidEscape": true, "allowTemplateLiterals": true }]
}
```

However, when running e.g. `ng g c my-component` a component is created with single quotes for the imports.

`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';` <- Single quotes

Is it possible to configure Angular with ESLint so that the CLI enforces the rules I have configured in `.eslintrc.json`?

Comment: You'd have to create your own compliant blueprints, why not just run ESLint with `--fix` after creating the new component?

Comment: That's an extra step :) Do you know where I can find documentation about "compliant blueprints"?

Comment: Well it's that or https://angular.io/guide/schematics-authoring

Comment: I see, thanks for the link.

Comment: nice question but the solution is too painful to bother with